# How to do a "reveal"-style collapse/expand animation in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

I'd like to implement an animation in SwiftUI that "reveals" the content of a view to enable expand/collapse functionality. The content of the view I want to collapse and expand is complex: It's not just a simple box, but it's a view hierarchy of dynamic height and content, including images and text.

I've experimented with different options, but it hasn't resulted in the desired effect. Usually what happens is that when I "expand", the whole view was shown right away with 0% opacity, then gradually faded in, with the buttons under the expanded view moving down at the same time. That's what happened when I was using a conditional `if` statement that actually added and removed the view. So that makes sense.

I then experimented with using a `frame` modifier: `.frame(maxHeight: isExpanded ? .infinity : 0)`. But that resulted in the contents of the view being "squished" instead of revealed.

I made a paper prototype of what I want:

[image: paper prototype]

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: This should be helpful (see also link inside this answer) https://stackoverflow.com/a/62482773/12299030.

Comment: @Asperi thank you very much!

Comment: Just want to say I greatly appreciate your paper prototype, I've seen hundreds of stack overflow questions over the years and this is one of the best :-)!

Comment: @EytanSchulman Haha, thanks so much for taking the time to write that :) It was fun to make, and it was easier to convey what I wanted as opposed to using many words :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Something like this might work. You can modify the height of what you want to disclose to be 0 when hidden or `nil` when not so that it'll go for the height defined by the views. Make sure to clip the view afterwards so the contents are not visible outside of the frame's height when not disclosed.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var isDisclosed = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Expand") {
                withAnimation {
                    isDisclosed.toggle()
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.plain)
            
            
            VStack {
                GroupBox {
                    Text("Hi")
                }
                
                GroupBox {
                    Text("More details here")
                }
            }
            .frame(height: isDisclosed ? nil : 0, alignment: .top)
            .clipped()
            
            HStack {
                Text("Cancel")
                Spacer()
                Text("Book")
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .background(.thinMaterial)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

No, this wasn't trying to match your design, either. This was just to provide a sample way of creating the animation.

Comment: Brilliant! That's exactly what I needed, thanks so much! I think the combination of `clipped` and `alignment: .top` is the key.

Comment: This can glitch if the text spans multiple lines.

Comment: I have unwanted jumps in cell content for this solution, even if I using your sample code (iOS 16+)

Comment: @Rick Did you find a way to overcome the problem with multi-line text?

Comment: I found that for the multiline text this approach works better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69351476/7016052.

Answer (score 11):

Consider the utilization of `DisclosureGroup`. The following code should be a good approach to your idea.

```
struct ContentView: View {
var body: some View {
    List(0...20, id: \.self) { idx in
        DisclosureGroup { 
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "person.circle.fill")
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("ABC")
                    Text("Test Test")
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "globe")
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("ABC")
                    Text("X Y Z")
                }
            }
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "water.waves")
                VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                    Text("Bla Bla")
                    Text("123")
                }
            }
            HStack{
                Button("Cancel", role: .destructive) {}
                Spacer()
                Button("Book") {}
            }
        } label: { 
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Text("Expand")
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

The result looks like:

[image: Result]

I coded this in under 5 minutes. So of course the design can be optimized to your demands, but the core should be understandable.

Answer (score 1):

```
import SwiftUI

struct TaskViewCollapsible: View {
    @State private var isDisclosed = false
    let header: String = "Review Page"
    let url: String
    let tasks: [String]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                VStack(spacing: 5) {
                    Text(header)
                        .font(.system(size: 22, weight: .semibold))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(.top, 10)
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                    
                    Text(url)
                        .font(.system(size: 12, weight: .regular))
                        .foregroundColor(.black.opacity(0.4))
                        .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Image(systemName: self.isDisclosed ? "chevron.up" : "chevron.down")
                    .padding(.trailing)
                    .padding(.top, 10)
                    
            }
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation {
                    isDisclosed.toggle()
                }
            }
            
            FetchTasks()
                .padding(.horizontal, 20)
                .padding(.bottom, 5)
                .frame(height: isDisclosed ? nil : 0, alignment: .top)
                .clipped()
        }
        .background(
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .fill(.black.opacity(0.2))
        )
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        .padding()
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func FetchTasks() -> some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: true) {
            VStack {
                ForEach(0 ..< tasks.count, id: \.self) { value in
                    Text(tasks[value])
                        .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .regular))
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .padding(.vertical, 0)
                        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: CGFloat(tasks.count) * 20)
    }
}

struct TaskViewCollapsible_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TaskViewCollapsible(url: "trello.com", tasks: ["Hello", "Hello", "Hello"])
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Check out DisclosureGroup. I believe this can suit your requirements: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/disclosuregroup